# Multidimensional array function don't stop at "return"

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-4

This is multidimensional array:

```
$group_tree =  Array
   (
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1   
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [7] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7

                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )


                                )

                        )

                )

        )


)
```

and this is the recursive function ( $group_id = 6 ) i use:

```
  public static function sub_group_tree( $group_tree , $group_id )
    {   

        foreach ( $group_tree as $key => $value ) { 

            echo  "<br>key : $key and group id is $group_id <br>"  ;

            if( (int) $key == $group_id ) {

                echo "check";

                return $value;

            }

            if( count($value['children']) ){            

                Group::sub_group_tree( $value['children'] ,  $group_id  ) ;
            }

        }


    }
```

The strange thing is that i get back the "return" as null , but if i use "die($value)" instead of "return",then i see $value as the right portion of the multidimensional array.
It look like the "return" doesn't break the loop, and the loop continue although the condition is fill, the word "check" will be printed in test of the function return values. 
see the result :

```
key : 1 and group id is 6 
key : 6 and group id is 6 
check
null
```

i use Laravel on php 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static function sub_group_tree( $group_tree , $group_id )
{ 

    ...
    if( count($value['children']) ) {
        return Group::sub_group_tree( $value['children'] ,  $group_id  ) ;
    }
    ...

}
```

The problem is that you are not returning the result from `sub_group_tree()` in your `if( count($value['children']) ) { }`.

Comment: OO - will at least need `$this->`

Comment: sorry about that. i was trying on local server without OOP.

Comment: @t-coder thanks, the "return" before the second call to the function change it all

Answer (score 0):

One: You shouldn't be returning half way through a function, you should be setting a variable like `$return` to the value you want, then `return $return` at the **end** of the function.

Two: When you recursively call `sub_group_tree`, you aren't assigning a variable to contain the result, so the return on that function is pointless...

```
Group::sub_group_tree( $value['children'] ,  $group_id  ) ;
```